# How to remove double Quotes In DataStage using a transformer stage?

Tags: datastage

We receiving Input data like below
“VENKATA,KRISHNA”

I want output like below
VENKATA,KRISHNA

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Ereplace](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=functions-ereplace-function) function - it allows to replace certain characters so you could rplace " with '' (empty string).

An alternative is [TRIM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=functions-trim-function) - you can specify which character the command should trim and also if All occurrences or Both (from both sides of the string) plus more.

Comment: I used the TRIM function and it's working correctly Thanks, Michael

Comment: If it is a solution for your problem please mark it as solution - thanks